# Suppression + Mediation?

Tags: regression, spss

I have a suppressioneffect, because a correlation between x and y is actually non-significant, but if I put in another variable (in a multiple regression), then the correlation between x and y becomes significant. Now is my question if this is also a partial mediation? Because in a multiple regression x and the third variable are significant and the ANOVA ist significant too. Or is this only a suppressioneffect?